# Splitting field into several fields based on strings separated by space in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I need to create dichotomic fields based on a single field which shows multiple choice answers in the form of strings separated by a space. What I want to do is this:

[image]

The number of choices that will produce the new fields is known, but I have 27 fields with data from multiple choice questions in several layers, I know how to do this manually, but it would take a very long time.

update:
Here is a screenshot of one of my field of interest, there are blank spaces, there are no "0" because the multiple-choice options begin with "1". When in a group this field is not filled (because it depends on previous selections) then it becomes blank.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the fields with an expression such as below. For example, create `FIELD_1` with expression

```
if(array_contains(string_to_array(data, ' '), 1), 1, 0)
```

The expression looks at a field `data` and if it contains `1` returns 1 otherwise 0. You can repeat the process for all the fields you need to create.

As your problem requires you to repeat this multiple times, you can use a little bit of pyqgis to automate it. Select the layer containing the data. Open a python console in QGIS with the layer selected and copy/paste the following code and hit Enter. change `num_choices` to number of fields you require and `data` with the field containing the data.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
num_choices = 5
for x in range(1, num_choices+1):
  field = QgsField( 'FIELD_{}'.format(x), QVariant.String )
  idx = layer.addExpressionField("if(array_contains(string_to_array(data, ' '), {}), 1, 0)".format(x), field)
```

For a test layer with your test data, I get the following output in QGIS3.4

[image]

Comment: Hi! for some reason when I update the field name in the console, whether I use "or not, It doesn´t seem to update, so I figure out that updating the field name in the layer properties does what I need. So this is definitely the right solution.